Построение на flex
Помогите решить один ребус для меня. Мне нужно сверстать одну страницу которая состоит из трех частей header, main, footer
<body>
    <header></header>
    <main></main>
    <footer></footer>
</body>

В main надо вложить 4 блока
<main>
  <div class="div_1"></div>
  <div class="div_2"></div>
  <div class="div_3"></div>
  <div class="div_4"></div>
</main>

Вот сам css
body {
  background-color: black;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}
header {
  flex: 0 0 55px;
  background-color: grey;
}

main {
  flex: 1 1 calc(100dvh - 110px);
  background-color: yellow;
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}

footer {
  flex: 0 0 55px;
  background-color: green;
}

.div_1 {
  background-color: blue;
  flex: 0 0 50%;
}

.div_2 {
  background-color: pink;
  flex: 0 0 50%;
}

.div_3 {
  background-color: aqua;
  flex: 0 0 50%;
}

.div_4 {
  background-color: blueviolet;
  flex: 0 0 50%;
}

Подскажите пожалуйста как то можно зафиксировать main под размер разрешения экрана что бы при сужении браузера по высоте у меня блоки оставались без изменения по высоте и не изменялся background?
